# Unity Multiplayer Sync Bools

Tags: unity, networking, multiplayer, unity-networking, mirror-networking

I have a little problem with syncing booleans on my networking game.

I use the Mirror-Package for networking and use KCP for transport.

When the players basicly collide each other ***(**using a sphere trigger box for detection**)*** they should change their state from false to true or otherwise.

Sometimes it is working and sometimes booth get the same state displayed by color - ***the problem mostly accures when running.***

Tested with a friend - ***the color get synced correctly*** but ***the booleans sometimes do not get set correctly.*** For debugging purposes the state can be changed by key press.

Thanks for advice!

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)                  // Getting called a player enter collision
{
    if (isLocalPlayer)                                       // Check if this is local player
    {
        if (other.gameObject != gameObject)                  // Double check it not own body - problematic on begging
        {
            if (cooldown == false)                           // Make sure player is not on cooldown 
            {
                if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))   // Make sure the gameobject has right tag 
                {
                    ChangePlayerState(caught);               // Call function an pass in current state which is a boolean
                }
            }
        }
    }                                                                
}

#region Player State

[Client]
public void ChangePlayerState(bool state)                         
{
    cooldown = true;                                          // Activate cooldown

    if (state == true)                                        // Do logic for true
    {
        caught = false;
        stateLight.color = Color.green;
    } 
    else 
    if (state == false)                                       // Do logic for false
    {
        caught = true;
        stateLight.color = Color.red;
    }

    Invoke("ChangeCooldown", 3);

                                                             // Networking-Part - Changing only color when networking

    if (isClient) CmdChangePlayerState(caught);              // Execute Command
    if (isServer) RpcChangePlayerState(caught);              // Execute Rpc

}

[Command]
private void CmdChangePlayerState(bool state)                // Change color according to statebool
{
    if (state == true)
    {
        stateLight.color = Color.red;
    }

    else

    if (state == false)
    {
        stateLight.color = Color.green;
    }
}

[ClientRpc]
private void RpcChangePlayerState(bool state)                // Change color according to statebool
{
    if (state == true)
    {
        stateLight.color = Color.red;
    }

    else

    if (state == false)
    {
        stateLight.color = Color.green;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by calling the initial `OnTriggerEnter` event only on the server.

***The server*** changes the state for itself, and then for the player.